# How to build non-duplication explicit word text-context counter in configurable way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

Here's my data

```
Id  Patient_id  Month  Text
1            1  1      Your heart is in somewhat dangerous condition
2            1  1      Your heart on very dangerous condition
3            1  1      Your lung is on dangerous condition
4            1  2      Your heart is in good condition
5            1  2      Your heart is in a state that is very dangerous condition
6            2  1      Your heart is in very dangerous condition
7            2  1      Your heart is on dangerous condition
8            2  1      Your heart is on great condition
9            2  1      Your lung is in good condition
10           2  1      Your heart is in a state that is very ambiguous condition
```

I need to count the instances of `heart` and `dangerous conditions`. In this analysis Id `1` and Id `2` are assumed to be equal, so counted as 1 , because they come from different doctors.

So, the desired output is:

```
Patient_id  Heart_Dangerous_Condition
1           2
2           1
```

Here's my code:

```
df = df.assign(**df.Text.str.extractall('(heart|dangerous condition)')[0]
              .str.get_dummies().sum(level=0))
df = df[(df['heart'] >= 1) & (df['dangerous condition'] == 0)]
df['one'] = 1
df = df[['Patient_id','one', 'Month']]
df.columns = ['customer_id','Heart_Dangerous_Condition', 'Month']
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = DataFrame({'count' : df.groupby( [ "Patient_id"] ).size()}).reset_index()
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need compare by sets, filter, remove duplicates and get counts per groups:

```
#create set of all values in row
s = {'heart','dangerous condition'}
#join with \b for word boundary
pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(s))

#extract values per rows, convert to set for compare
df = df[df.Text.str.findall(pat).apply(set) == s]
   Id  Patient_id  Month                                               Text
0   1           1      1      Your heart is in somewhat dangerous condition
1   2           1      1             Your heart on very dangerous condition
4   5           1      2  Your heart is in a state that is very dangerou...
5   6           2      1          Your heart is in very dangerous condition
6   7           2      1               Your heart is on dangerous condition

#remove duplicates and get counts
df = (df.drop_duplicates(['Patient_id','Month'])
        .groupby("Patient_id")
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df)
   Patient_id  count
0           1      2
1           2      1
```